# facebook comments box plugin does not have view xx comments in website posts

Tags: json, wordpress, facebook-comments

I'm a beginner in facebook.
I try to add the facebook comments box to each of my blog post,  i limit it to show 2 comments from the plugins, from the facebook comments box plugin site, they set the url to example.com and it show a whole different UI from what i got.

More importantly, there is no view XX comments after 2nd comment, even i added 20 comments to it.

May i know how can i solve it? is it some setting that i need to set in my facebook app or use the graph api, i know that i can get the json from the facebook graph site as mentioned in the facebook blog developers.facebook.com/blog/post/490/

if i need to solve using json way, how do i append the remaining comments inside the website where it is using iframe.

i wish to have a easier solution like just changing setting inside my facebook app, rather than code an "View xx comments" button to do ajax call and append the result to the dom myself.

Comment: solved myself, didn't remove the bracket after removing it, it is working now.